# send variables from php to jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

ive got a forum. when i click on a thread it passes GET variables through URL to another php page that displays that thread.

```
 url?threadid=10
```

and ive got a reply form in the bottom. when the user click submit reply it will execute jquery that call a php through ajax. i have to pass the threadid variable to the ajaxcalled php file but i dont know how to do that.

ive tried in phpfile:

```
  $threadid = $_GET['threadid'];
  include "jsfile.php";
```

and then in jsfile:

```
  <script ...> 
  $.get("static/js/ajaxcall_reply.php", {threadid: '<?php echo $threadid ?>'}, function(data) {
  </script>
```

but that doesnt work. how can i do it? what is the right way to go here. cookies? json? please help!

EDIT: btw...isnt this approach bad. because to be able to have php code in js file i have to include it as a php file and cant use  to link to it in php file? im a little bit lost...

Comment: You have a 0% accept record with 23 questions (all with answers).  Time to mark some of those with correct answers.

Comment: your approach is correct. maybe a programming mistake? turn on error_reporting and display_errors or check your error logs.

Comment: Is the jquery sample you provided above in the php page that shows the thread & reply form or is it being included from another file?  To see the php variable $threadid, you'll need to have the jquery call in the same page as the php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`threadid` is a request variable, so I think you'd need to get that from the `$_GET` array:

```
$.get("static/js/ajaxcall_reply.php", {threadid: '<?php echo $_GET["threadid"] ?>'}, function(data) {
```

[This page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) describes the `$_GET` array in more detail.  It contains request variables from the URL.  The array I had previously suggested [(`$_REQUEST`)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) would also work.

Comment: Yeah, $_GET would work too, and would actually ensure that it's using the URL variable.  Might avoid some potential problems with variables in other contexts.  I'll change it to that.

Comment: Maybe he's calling extract() on $_REQUEST, which i would never do.